# CodeIgniter 3 / Basic Hook Loading Problems

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

Hey I'm sure I miss something obvious, but can't figure out what it is :
I can't get a simple hook working with my quasi blank installation of CI 3 ...

I've put the simplest of the code possible with a Hook called `MyTest` **and it works fine** :

application/config/hooks.php

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'MyTest',
    'function' => 'TestMe',
    'filename' => 'MyTest.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'  => ''
 );
```

application/hooks/MyTest.php

```
class MyTest{

     function TestMe()
     {
         die("die by the hook TEST");
     }

 }
```

->this outputs "die by the hook TEST", which is what is expected.

But almost the same with a Hook called `URI_Actions` **doesn't work at all** :

application/config/hooks.php

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'URI_Actions',
    'function' => 'index',
    'filename' => 'URI_Actions.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'  => ''
 );
```

application/hooks/URI_Actions.php

```
class URI_Actions{

     function index()
     {
         die("die by the hook URI Actions");
     }

 }
```

-> this doesn't output anything ... I'm sure I'm missing something enormous, any idea ?

### Epilogue

Of course the problem was elsewhere : binary FTP transfert was the issue, *once the files uploaded normally the same codes worked perfectly*. Thanks to trajchevska which made me realize the code was not the problem !

Comment: I wonder whether to delete this question or not : Would have I found it in my search, it would have helped me for sure ... but is this really relevant according to the fact the solution has nothing to do with the question ?

Answer (score 1):

Does it not display anything or it displays "die by the hook TEST" only? The thing is that you have them both defined one after the other and they're both doing dump and die. So when the Test hook displays the result, the program dies and doesn't get to the URI_Actions hook.

Try using a simple var_dump instead of die, you should get the expected result. I tested both locally and they work fine.

Comment: hi,thanks for answer, I don't use both hooks at the same time, but I tried to declare them and replace die by var_dump as you suggested.. And it works !.. But when I remove MyTest from the /config/hooks.php and leave only URI_Actions it does not work anymore ..

Comment: Ok, i missed the point, it works in local definitely, uri_actions alone.. I think I might have had a binary ftp transfert problem with my ftp client (i'm also working with binary file transfert) cause when uploading them again it works like a charm .. I'll delete my question then , thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: That's strange. It's still working for me, even after removing the test hook. I'm sure you're missing something. If it was working with the var_dump, then it enters the hook function, so it shouldn't be affected by the existence of the other hook. Can you paste the content of your hooks file and the class after the changes?